# Is the set of symmetric positive-definite matrices open in the set of symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices

I'm not sure if the set of symmetric positive-definite matrices is open in the set of symmetric matrices.  I'm almost certain that it is not open in the larger set of n by n matrices.  So far most of the proofs I've seen don't use symmetry, so I'm not sure if they are correct.  Any hints?  I've been trying to use that the set of positive-definite matrices is path connected, but I can't come up with a solution.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does positive-definite mean if you're not a symmetric matrix? Anyway, yes - this is equivalent to saying that $x^T A x$ is positive for all nonzero $x$, which is equivalent to saying that $x_i^T Ax_i$ is positive for the basis vectors $x_i$. This last condition, then, is clearly an open condition.

Comment: @Mike Miller, don't we need to show that any matrix within some distance of A is also positive-definite?

Comment: Yes, [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) implies that any  matrix $A'$ which is sufficiently close to a positive-definite matrix $A$ is positive-definite (of course, provided $A'$ is symmetric).

Comment: Here's a more direct proof. Sylvester's criterion mentioned by @AlexRavsky shows that the set of positive-definite matrices is the intersection of the set of symmetric matrices and the set $\{A\mid\text{det}A_k>0,k=1,2,\ldots,n\}$, which is the intersection of inverse images of a open set under the continuous determinant map.

Comment: @MikeMiller why is it enough to check on a basis?

Comment: @peter if $x = \sum c_i x_i$ then $x^T A x = \sum c_i^2 x_i^T A x_i$; all of the terms are non-negative and one of them is non-zero by assumption $x \neq 0$.

Comment: @MikeMiller how did you get rid of the different indices of the two basis vectors in your (double-)sum?

Comment: @peter yep, seems like I made a mistake. Instead it seems easier to demand positivity on the compact space given by the unit sphere, which still shows that this forms an open set, but that is more complicated.